# HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error) while using Zend google calendar Api

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

I want to sync my application with Google calendar, while I am using **Zend Google Calendar API**, when I given the Gmail username and password, the API gives the token and refresh the page with URL:

> http://dev.example.com/prac/googlecalendar?token=1%2FLH52gw1KqpZKBXDdTqTIJMTIBO_DIhfMH3_VKhPMfKY

when it come back to my function again after given the token..so it come to this function:

```
$client = getAuthSubHttpClient();
```

and never come back with `$client` object and encountered this error:

> The website encountered an error and  It may be down for maintenance
>   or configured incorrectly.

Comment: Are you following this example? If so, ensure the function is defined: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html#zend.gdata.calendar.connecting.service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you check for Fatal Errors in PHP code:

Put below lines on top of your code, check if its showing any Fatal error

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Hope this help

~K

Comment: Yes got the error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function getAuthSubHttpClient()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not have included all needet scripts or classes.

Please ensure, that everything is included and alle needed extensions are installed at you PHP-Host.